# Outlook Keeps Popping Up Download History When Downloading Attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

When I download an attachment in Outlook, the app will pop-up the "Download History" Window away from my Outlook window, sometimes on my second monitor. In those cases I am unable to close it because the window cannot be dragged down and will open outside of the screen upwards:

[image]

How can I disable this Download popup window within Outlook?

I am clicking on Download as below, not "Save".

[image]

I am aware that saving to OneDrive and seeing the attachments folder bypasses the problem, but I would not like to use OneDrive space, only local space.

Comment: By "download an attachment", do you mean "save as" ?

Comment: @harrymc No. I added another picture to clarify this.

Comment: I assume you're on Windows. What do you see when you click on the 3-dots button at the top of the Downloads window?

Comment: Does [this old thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-file-download-screen-pop-up-when/ff53377f-a176-4c06-b0b2-4dc8d8021c2f) help?

Comment: @1NN No because that's Outlook 2010. It uses a different UI.

Answer (score 1):

The new Outlook client uses Microsoft Edge as the rendering engine ([WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/webview2-api-reference)). Modifying the `Show downloads menu when a download starts` setting in the Edge browser (as mentioned by @Faery) does not apply to Outlook.

[There is some discussion ongoing between developers,](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2638#issuecomment-1527121075) about the best way to disable related behaviour when implementing WebView2 in other applications/software ([such as this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadstartingeventargs.handled)).

I understand that without Microsoft specifically exposing this setting in Outlook, disabling this functionality will not be possible. I suggest [providing feedback directly to Microsoft.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/contact-support-and-provide-feedback-within-the-new-outlook-for-windows-4a4bcc80-c71e-4e44-97c1-d0e62452ef4a)

Comment: I've contacted support...let's see if they're able to resolve it or at least respond with progress.

Answer (score -1):

Look like you are using Outlook for the web.

To clear your download history, press **Ctrl+J** on your keyboard and click the menu button (three dots) in the upper-right corner. Then, select **Clear all download history**. Click **Remove All** in the warning pop-up to confirm. (This only deletes the list, not the actual files that you've downloaded.)

[image]

Besides, if you don't want the warning pop-pup, press **Ctrl+J** on your keyboard, click the menu button (three dots) in the upper-right corner. Then select **Download settings**,then uncheck the option.
[image]

Comment: Cool to know, but this is not Outlook for Web. This is the new Outlook that looks similar to the web, but it's a desktop application part of the Office suite of apps.